# Dynamic PDF and opening a new window instead of downloading

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, blob

I have a web api that is returning a JSReport as an encoded byte array. No matter how i try and read the byte array I either get a black screen or an error message that says "failed to download pdf". If I create a hidden anchor tag and download the pdf it works fine. However, I do not want the user to download it, I would prefer they can view it right from their browser.

**WEB API CALL**

```
   var data = LossReportService.GetLossSummary(request);
   var pdf_bytes = LossReportService.GeneratePDFUsingJSReport(data);

   byte[] myBinary = new byte[pdf_bytes.Length];
   pdf_bytes.Read(myBinary, 0, (int)pdf_bytes.Length);
   string base64EncodedPDF = System.Convert.ToBase64String(myBinary);

   var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, base64EncodedPDF);
   response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
   response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = pdf_bytes.Length;

   return response;
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Reporting/GetLossSummary",
    data: { dataObj },
},
success: function (data) {
   if (data != null) {

    //I have tried this
    var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf;base64' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    window.open(fileURL, "LossSummaryReport");

    //which gives me a "failed to load pdf document" error

    //and I have tried this, which just renders a blank page
    window.open("data:application/pdf," + encodeURI(data)); 
  }
}
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't added the document/content to the response

Comment: You have also mime-type/data-uri format mixed up. If the returned data is ArrayBuffer then set mime-type for blob only to type: 'application/pdf'. If you choose data-uri approach, also specify base64 (although it's default): window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + ...

Comment: @daddygames - what do you mean I haven't added the document/content to the response? content from the API is in "base64EncodedPDF " and being added to the response object in the api.

Comment: @K3N - even if I switch what you mention above neither situation work.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the code. Have you inspected the data variable in the Javascript success function? Is that variable coming back as the base64 representation of the PDF file? Or does it at least look like a base64 string value?

Comment: It appears to be encoded correctly. I currently have a hidden href tag with a download attribute and am downloading the file that way -- which works fine but doesn't open the file in a new window automatically. I have to click the downloaded file first.

Answer (score 1):

since you are using jsreport, in a normal case, you can use the [jsreport browser sdk](https://jsreport.net/learn/browser-client) to better work with the report result and to easily show it in browser. but in your case, you are using a custom url in your server to render your report, so the jsreport browser sdk can't help you in that case. you need instead to work with the report request and response with either jQuery ajax or plain XMLHttpRequest.

working with blob/binary data is hard to do it with jQuery.ajax, you would need to [add a data transport to $.ajax in order to handle binary data](http://www.henryalgus.com/reading-binary-files-using-jquery-ajax/)

```
/**
 *
 * jquery.binarytransport.js
 *
 * @description. jQuery ajax transport for making binary data type requests.
 * @version 1.0 
 * @author Henry Algus <henryalgus@gmail.com>
 *
 */

// use this transport for "binary" data type
$.ajaxTransport("+binary", function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR){
    // check for conditions and support for blob / arraybuffer response type
    if (window.FormData && ((options.dataType && (options.dataType == 'binary')) || (options.data && ((window.ArrayBuffer && options.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) || (window.Blob && options.data instanceof Blob)))))
    {
        return {
            // create new XMLHttpRequest
            send: function(headers, callback){
        // setup all variables
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = options.url,
        type = options.type,
        async = options.async || true,
        // blob or arraybuffer. Default is blob
        dataType = options.responseType || "blob",
        data = options.data || null,
        username = options.username || null,
        password = options.password || null;

                xhr.addEventListener('load', function(){
            var data = {};
            data[options.dataType] = xhr.response;
            // make callback and send data
            callback(xhr.status, xhr.statusText, data, xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());
                });

                xhr.open(type, url, async, username, password);

        // setup custom headers
        for (var i in headers ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(i, headers[i] );
        }

                xhr.responseType = dataType;
                xhr.send(data);
            },
            abort: function(){
                jqXHR.abort();
            }
        };
    }
});
```

but when handling blob data in an request/response i prefer doing it with XHTMLRequest directly because it let me manipulate the response in any way i want.

```
function sendReportRequest (dataObj, cb) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  var data = JSON.stringify(dataObj)

  xhr.open('POST', 'http://url-of-your-server/' + '/Reporting/GetLossSummary', true)
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
  xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer'

  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
      var response = xhr.response
      var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')
      var dataView = new DataView(response)
      var blob

      try {
        blob = new Blob([dataView], { type: contentType })
        cb(null, blob)
      } catch (e) {
        if (e.name === 'InvalidStateError') {
          var byteArray = new Uint8Array(response)
          blob = new Blob([byteArray.buffer], { type: contentType })
          cb(null, blob)
        } else {
          cb(new Error('Can not parse buffer response'))
        }
      }
    } else {
      var error = new Error('request failed')

      error.status = xhr.status
      error.statusText = xhr.statusText

      cb(error)
    }
  }

  xhr.onerror = function () {
    var error = new Error('request failed')

    error.status = xhr.status
    error.statusText = xhr.statusText

    cb(error)
  }

  xhr.send(data)
}

sendReportRequest(dataObj, function (err, reportBlob) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err)
  }

  var reportFileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(reportBlob)

  window.open(reportFileUrl)
})
```

with this piece of code you should be able to request a pdf file and show it right in the browser in a new window

Comment: Hello and thank you for the above. However I need to be able to send JSON data and it does not appear the above call accepts JSON data. Per this website https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send 

    A body of data to be sent in the XHR request. This can be:

        A Document, in which case it is serialized before being sent.
        A BodyInit, which as per the Fetch spec can be a Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, ReadableStream, or USVString object.

Comment: yes, the code in `sendReportRequet` is sending json data. if you look closely at developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send website you can see that one of the examples include sending a string, which for this case is the json body of the request `JSON.stringify(dataObj)` and that along with the correct header `xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')` makes passing json to the server correctly. have you tried the code? does not work for you? i've tried it locally and it works fine.